# Magento 2 dropdown not showing

Tags: magento2, topmenu, drop-downs

In my catalog I have some categories and subcategories with product.

But in my top nav I don't have any dropdown.

What I have missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check here :
`Store / Configuration / Catalog / Catalog / Category Top Navigation / Maximal Depth`

On my website the value is set on `0` and it works fine

Comment: It's working fine thanks !